# Why doesn't this SVG fit inside its parent DIV for small DIV sizes?

Tags: svg

My expectation is that the triangle should be inside the container div. This works as expected for widths bigger than 14 pixels or so, but for small div sizes the SVG gets bumped down.

```
<div id="square" style="width: 9px; height: 9px; background-color: red">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 99 99" style="width:100%; height: 100%; fill: blue;">
        <polygon
            id="triangle"
            points="0,99 49,0 99,99" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rpk6c6r0/4/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An `<svg>` element in HTML is set to `display: inline` by default.  This can cause it to be affected by line-wrapping when space is constrained; the icon will wrap to the next line in the same way as a word in a paragraph.

Easiest fix, if you are positioning the SVG precisely, is therefore to set `display: block`.

https://jsfiddle.net/rpk6c6r0/6/

Comment: Thanks so much Amelia. This is definitely a forehead slapper as I've encountered this same issue with inline elements before. =(

Comment: @AmeliaBR There have been some discussions about SVGs being inline elements in the comments to [*"Put 2 svg side by side"*](/q/44073386) which are still not settled. Could you provide any further insight or reference on why SVGs are inline rather than block elements?

Comment: Thank you Amelia. I've been looking for an answer to this issue for hours. What do you recommend if the SVG is wrapped inside an anchor tag? I thought setting SVG to`display: block` in an inline element is not recommended.